# how html form post in json

Tags: php, json

how HTML form post in JSON see below form screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="wheretogo.php" enctype='application/json'>

<!-- your complete form -->

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks alot for the suggestion, i will try my best to achieve the standards in future after this.